# Cómo generar array de objetos dentro de otro

Tags: php, php7

Tengo que construir **data**, pero necesito ayuda con products, no sé como escribir el código para generar el array **products** de objetos, solo sé generar el primer nivel (category)...muchas gracias!

```
private data = [
    {
      category: 'Pizza',
      products: [
        { id: 0, name: 'Salami', price: '8' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Classic', price: '5' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Tuna', price: '9' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Hawai', price: '7' }
      ]
    },
    {
      category: 'Pasta',
      products: [
        { id: 4, name: 'Mac & Cheese', price: '8' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Bolognese', price: '6' }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Mi código:

```
$arreglo = array();
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT category FROM tabla_1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $cat = $row["category "];
    
    $arreglo [] = array('cat'=>$cat);
}

$json_string = json_encode($arreglo);
echo $json_string;
```

Answer (score 2):

Pues es que casi lo tienes. Para rematarlo, yo haría algo así:

```
$rs = $conn->query("
    SELECT * FROM categories
      JOIN products USING(id_category);
");

$data=[];
$cat=null;
while($r=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
    if($cat!=$r['id_category']){
        $cat=$r['id_category'];
        $data[$cat]=[
            'category'=>$r['category'],
            'products'=>[],
        ];
    }
    $data[$cat]['products'][]=[
        'id'=>$r['id'],
        'name'=>$r['name'],
        'price'=>$r['price'],
    ];
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($data,true).'</pre>'
    .json_encode($data)
    .'<script>data='.json_encode($data)
    .';console.log(data);</script>';
```

A partir de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE categories(
  id_category int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  category varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE products(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(31),
  price float,
  id_category int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_category) REFERENCES categories(id_category)
  );
INSERT INTO categories (category) VALUES
  ('Pizza'),('Pasta');
INSERT INTO products (name, price, id_category) VALUES
  ('Salami',8,1),('Classic',5,1),('Tuna',9,1),('Hawai',7,1),
  ('Mac & Cheese',8,2),('Bolognese',6,2);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias David!

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Comment: Creo David que no puedo aceptarla como mejor respuesta, no sé si mis puntos alcanzan, debajo de la cant de votos positivos, solo tengo un reloj.

Comment: Pues no lo sé, pero te acabo de votar la pregunta para que tengas 10 puntos más. Aquí dice que hay que esperar 15 minutos, pero no habla de reputación mínima: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas